# $f(z) = \bar{z}^2$ is differentiable only at $z = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Show directly from the definition of the derivative that the function $f(z) = \bar{z}^2$ is differentiable only at $z = 0$ (Do not use Cauchy Riemann Equation). Can someone help me on this. The definition we will use is

$$f'(z) = \lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}$$

edit (not familiar with this platform.. accidently delete all I typed.):
Basically I get to this point and don't know how to approach this further.

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{(\bar{z}+\bar{h})^2-\bar{z}}{h} = \lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{2\bar{z}\bar{h}+\bar{h}^2}{h}$$

More Edit:

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{2\bar{z}\bar{h}+\bar{h}^2}{h} = \lim_{h\rightarrow0} \Big(\frac{2\bar{z}\bar{h}}{h}+\frac{\bar{h}^2}{h}\Big)$$

If $z\neq 0$ then the first part of the limit wouldn't exist. But what if $z = 0$? How can we show the limit actually exist when $z=0$.

Comment: Hint: Use the definition

Comment: So where are you stuck? Can you tell what $f(z+h)$ means, for instance?

Comment: sorry for not specifing something correctly.

Comment: $$f(z+h) = (\overline{z+h})^2 = (\bar{z} + \bar{h})^2 = \bar{z}^2 + 2\bar{z}\bar{h} + \bar{h}^2$$

Comment: Try letting $h = t$ for $t \in \mathbb{R}$, and evaluate the limit as $t \to 0$. Then, let $h = it$ and do the same.

Comment: @Joppy I understand that $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}(\bar{h}/h)$ does not exist so the limit wouldn't exist. But how do we show the limit do exist at 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z_0 = x_0 + i y_0 $ in $\mathbb{C}$.

Note that

$$
\frac{f(z_0 + h) - f(z_0)}{h} = \frac{[(x_0+h_1)-i(y_0+h_2)]^2 - (x_0 - iy_0)^2}{h},
$$
where $h = h_1+i h_2$.

Simple calculation:

$$\frac{[(x_0+h_1)-i(y_0+h_2)]^2 - (x_0 - iy_0)^2}{h} = \frac{(2 \overline{z_0} + \overline{h}) \, \overline{h}}{h}.$$

Note that $$\left| \frac{\overline{h}\overline{h}}{h} \right| \leq |h| $$ for $h \neq 0$, hence $\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\overline{h}\overline{h}} {h} =0$.

However, $\frac{\overline{h}}{h}$ doesn't converges as $h \rightarrow 0$ (see Joppy's comment).

Thus, $\frac{2 \overline{ z_0} \overline{h}}{h}$ doesn't converges as $h \rightarrow 0$ unless $z_0 = 0$.

Comment: Could you be a little bit more explicit on how you bound $|\overline{hh}/h|$?

Comment: @SeanZhou It is obvious that $| \overline{hh} | = | h^2| =|h|^2$.

Comment: This method works intuitively. But do you know any standard way to calculate $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\overline{hh}}{h}$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:)**

For $z\neq0$
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{2\bar{z}\bar{h}+\bar{h}^2}{h} = \lim_{h\rightarrow0} \dfrac{\bar{h}}{h}(2\bar{z}+\bar{h})$$
this limit doesn't exist, check it with $h=x+iy$ when you approach to $0$ on $x$'axis and $y$'axis.

Comment: If the limit does not exist how can you do the second equation? And for example, $lim_{h\rightarrow0} \bar{h}/h * h$ do exist.

Comment: I think you cannot just split the limit like that..

Comment: Could you also put $f(z)=a^2-b^2-2abi$ and use C-R equations?

Comment: @anonymous yes. you can do it and post it as an good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Put $f(z)=\overline{z}^2$, then I claim that $f(z)$ is only differentiable at $0$.

To see this, putting $z=a+bi$, one has

$$f(z)=a^2-b^2-2abi.$$

Then if $f$ is differentiable everywhere, by way of contradiction, we have by the C-R equations, putting $u(a,b)=a^2-b^2, v(a,b)=-2ab$, then

$$-2a=2a, -2b=2b.$$

And this holds if and only if $a=0=b$, and we are done.

Comment: Note that the question explicitly asks *“Show directly from the definition of the derivative”* and *“Do not use Cauchy Riemann Equation.”*

Comment: @MartinR good catch I didn’t see that, I was told by Nosrati to post my solution.

Comment: @MartinR My approach is correct however right? Cause I had a qualifier in complex and answered using CR equations for this problem.